# Odd behaviour without whitespace for \newenvironment

Tags: environments

I'm very new to latex and am just learning things and want to understand why some code is behaving the way it is. I can't seem to find documentation regarding this specific behaviour.

Essentially I'm defining some new environments, and found that unless I included some whitespace between them, it would spit out a bunch of errors when compiled. I wouldn't have thought whitespace would be relevant if all the brackets were properly closed. Is there perhaps some bad code causing this?

This code works:

```
\newenvironment{summary}{\clearpage \thispagestyle{plain}}

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{\clearpage \thispagestyle{plain}}
```

This code does not work:

```
\newenvironment{summary}{\clearpage \thispagestyle{plain}}
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{\clearpage \thispagestyle{plain}}
```

This code also does not work:

```
\newenvironment{summary}{\clearpage \thispagestyle{plain}}
% comment
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{\clearpage \thispagestyle{plain}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax of `\newenvironment` **without** environment arguments is

```
\newenvironment{envname}{begin code}{end code}
```

You need 3 `{...}` argument groups, all your examples miss the explicit `{end code}` argument.

The reason why the first code works is the empty line between the two `\newenvironment` commands, the last `{}` (end code) is then assumed to contain a `\par` (Thanks to @clemens for improving my statement)

The others fail because the first `\newenvironment` reads `\newenviroment{...}` as the end code (which is possible,but wrong in syntax here)

Try:

```
\newenvironment{summary}{\clearpage \thispagestyle{plain}}{}
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{\clearpage \thispagestyle{plain}}{}
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense! Thank you for your explanation. My code is now working.

Comment: @Ulysses: Ok,that's fine. Happy TeXing!

Comment: With the empty line the `\end...` argument then isn't empty but contains a `\par`.

Comment: @clemens: Of course. I will add this to the answer

Comment: @clemens: Changed again :-P

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @clemens. Much appreciated.